# CSS selector best practices in component scope

Tags: css, angular, css-selectors, components

Component based frameworks (like Angular 2) scope the CSS related to a component. It means your component-css will not interfere with dom nodes outside this component.

In this situation, collateral effects due to vague selectors are no more relevant. Should we still use enforce the rules of specific CSS selector, or does it become pointless ? Phrased in a different way, is there any valid reason to keep using specific selectors ?

I'm not so much interested in a performance point of view, but rather in code architecture perspective.

Comment: What is "specific selectors" exactly?

Comment: I define a selector as specific when it leverages a combination of class and hierarchy to target precisely elements. Ex: a specific version of `li {... }` would be `.users > li.user {...}`. The first will match my DOM nodes, but may also match other nodes it was not written for. The second will reduce this risk.

Comment: It depends on the size of your components template, but for the common case you shouldn't need that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular components should be small and specialized, therefore complex selectors should not be necessary anymore.
Usually simple class selectors are enough and therefore using guidelines for complex multi-level selectors are redundant.

You probably still need to establish some guidelines for theming and selectors that cross component boundaries.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You still talk about simple class, in your mind would it be OK to defined selector on DOM elements ? (`ul` or `p` for instance)

Comment: Sure, you can also use tag names. With almost everything a component,  tag names are usually quite distinctive. Also attribute selectors work fine. You shouldn't need complex selectors though.